# Extract elements from a list to form a new list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `train_set` with 20 dataframes. I want to extract 10 dataframe in one list, and the remaining 10 in another list. I tried doing this `train_df1 <- train_set[[c(1:10)]]`, but it's giving me error.

Comment: `train_set[1:10]` - `[[` is for selecting *one* item only.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [The difference between bracket \[ \] and double bracket \[\[ \]\] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: @thelatemail thank you!!! I see where i made the mistake.